# Exception at initialization of DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime

I am initialiting `DateTime` variable in the parameters of a controller action as below

```
public ActionResult ForFahrzeug(DateTime initDat = default(DateTime), long id = 0, long   
                             days = 0, string ExpGnr = "")
    {
        //body
    }
```

There is no error at compile time but an exception occurred during runtime.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Encountered an invalid type for a default value.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web   
   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where    it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.FormatException: Encountered an invalid type for a default value.
```

Stack Trace:

```
[FormatException: Encountered an invalid type for a default value.]
System.Reflection.MdConstant.GetValue(MetadataImport scope, Int32 token, RuntimeTypeHandle   fieldTypeHandle, Boolean raw) +10764128
System.Reflection.RuntimeParameterInfo.GetDefaultValueInternal(Boolean raw) +413
System.Reflection.RuntimeParameterInfo.GetDefaultValue(Boolean raw) +31
System.Reflection.RuntimeParameterInfo.get_DefaultValue() +6
System.Web.Mvc.ParameterInfoUtil.TryGetDefaultValue(ParameterInfo parameterInfo, Object& value) +64
System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedParameterDescriptor.get_DefaultValue() +59
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +541
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +199
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +978
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +161
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +92
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag) +53
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +538
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__17(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +83
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +161
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +92
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +97
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate endDelegate, Object tag) +53
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +531
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +161
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +92
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +97
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate endDelegate, Object tag) +53
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +447
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +49
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +127
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +161
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +92 
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +97
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate endDelegate, Object tag) +53
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +388
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +88
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +50
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +301
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: Stack trace is updated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This behavior is reported here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/733995/datetime-default-parameter-value-throws-formatexception-at-runtime

Seems to be a bug.

You can optionally do it like this:

```
 public ActionResult ForFahrzeug(DateTime? initDat = null, ...
 {
 }
```

Comment: Or `DateTime initDat = DateTime.Now`.

Comment: @L-Three There is one more problem arizes due to this solution. For example I have two variable sof `DateTime` like `DateTime? initDate = null, DateTime? finalDate = null` and I want to find the difference. Then it does not work now. It seems the both variables are no more of type `DateTime`. I am find the difference `int days = (finalDate - initDate).TotalDays;`

Comment: You have to check if there are null before using them, by using HasValue. if (finalDate.HasValue) { ... }

Comment: @L-Three Like this? 
`if (initDate != null && finalDate != null)
{
   days = (int)(finalDate - initDate).TotalDays;
}`

Comment: if (initDate.HasValue && finalDate.HasValue) { days = (int)(finalDate - initDate).TotalDays; }

Comment: FYI: Microsoft resolved the Connect issue linked above as "Won't Fix", and the link doesn't work anymore. The last comment from MS on 4/6/2012 was: "Unfortunately, we cannot fix this issue right now. However, we have logged this bug and will revisit it as soon as the circumstances allow."